# Modify a parameter of a function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(setf list (loop for i from 1 to 12 collect i))
(defun removef (item seq)
  (setf seq (remove item seq)))


CL-USER> (removef 2 list)
(1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12)

CL-USER> (removef 3 list)
(1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12)
```

Why doesn't `removef` really modify the variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Common Lisp, parameters are passed "by identity" ([this term goes back to D. Rettig](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.lisp/PnzDrFzi5Jo/mBrN8RP-QzMJ), one of the developers of the Allegro Common Lisp implementation). Think of pointers (to heap objects) being passed by values, which is true for most Lisp objects (like strings, vectors, and, of course, lists; things are slightly more complicated, since implementations might also have immediate values, but that's beside the point here).

The `setf` of `seq` modifies the (private, lexical)  variable binding of the function. This change is not visible outside of `removef`.

In order for `removef` to be able to affect the surrounding environment at the point of the call, you need to make it a macro:

```
(defmacro removef (element place)
   `(setf ,place (remove ,element ,place)))
```

You might want to take at look at [`setf`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_setf_.htm) and the concept of [generalized references](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_a.htm). Note, that the macro version of `removef` I provided above is **not** how it should actually be done! For details, read about [`get-setf-expansion`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_get_se.htm#get-setf-expansion) and its ugly details.

If all you want to do is to destructively modify the list, consider using `delete` instead of remove, but be aware, that this might have unintended consequences:

```
(delete 2 '(1 2 3 4))
```

is not allowed by the ANSI standard (you are destructively modifying a literal object, i.e., part of your code). In this example, the mistake is easy to spot, but if you are 7 frames deep in some callstack, processing values whose origin is not entirely clear to you, this becomes a real problem. And anyway, even

```
(setf list (list 1 2 3 4))
(delete 1 list)
list
```

might be surprising at first, even though

```
(setf list (list 1 2 3 4))
(delete 2 list)
list
```

seems to "work". Essentially, the first example does not work as intended, as the function `delete` has the same problem as your original version of `removef`, namely, it cannot change the caller's notion of the `list` variable, so even for the destructive version, the right way to do it is:

```
(setf list (delete 1 (list 1 2 3 4)))
```

Comment: Though `define-setf-expander` is the most general case, `removef` can be implemented more easily using [`define-modify-macro`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_2.htm), if one is willing to use a different argument order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of an implementation of `removef` that is "able to affect the surrounding environment at the point of the call", as stated by @Dirk.

```
 (defmacro removef (item place &rest args &key from-end test test-not start end count key &environment env)
    (declare (ignore from-end test test-not start end count key))
    (multiple-value-bind (vars vals store-vars writer-form reader-form)
        (get-setf-expansion place env)
      (assert (length= store-vars 1) ()
              "removef only supports single-value places")
      (let ((v.args (make-gensym-list (length args)))
            (store-var (first store-vars)))
        (once-only (item)
          `(let* (,@(mapcar #'(lambda (var val)
                                `(,var ,val))
                            vars vals)
                  ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (v.arg arg)
                                `(,v.arg ,arg))
                            v.args args)
                    (,store-var (remove ,item ,reader-form ,@v.args)))
             ,writer-form)))))
```

The utilities [length=](http://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html#Sequences) , [make-gensym-list](http://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html#Symbols) and [once-only](http://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html#Macro-Writing) are available at Project [Alexandria](http://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/).

BTW exists at Alexandria a [removef](http://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html#Sequences) definition that uses [define-modify-macro](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_2.htm) but requires an auxiliary definition. This version does not requires an auxiliary defintion.